# Can a relativistic quantum particle be completely confined into a finite hole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, schroedinger-equation, klein-gordon-equation

If we write the Klein-Gordon equation in this form
\begin{equation*}
c^2 \hbar^2 \nabla^2 \Psi = \hbar^2 \ddot{\Psi} + 2i\hbar (U - mc^2) \dot{\Psi} + U (2mc^2 - U) \Psi 
\end{equation*} 
we have a pleasant sense of continuity from the non-relativistic to the relativistic treatment of quantum particle (we use the Schrödinger formalism, and to get the NR solutions we only have to put $c\to\infty$). The (not Lorentz invariant) equation has to be handled with care because the manipulations I used in order to obtain it, included squaring conservation of energy, so we can get spurious solutions too. But I think that for zero-spin particles it works, because I found it in page 42 of [Wachter's *Relativistic Quantum Mechanics*](http://books.google.lu/books/about/Relativistic_Quantum_Mechanics.html?id=NjZogv2yFzAC&redir_esc=y) (written slightly differently).

If we suppose that $|\Psi|^2$ is stationary  (i.e. the solution has the form $\Psi (\mathbf{r},t)  = \psi (\mathbf r) e^{Ct} $ with $C$ purely imaginary) the equation takes the time-independent form:
\begin{equation*}
-c^2 \hbar^2 \nabla^2 \Psi = [U^2 - 2(E+mc^2)U + E^2+2Emc^2] \Psi
\end{equation*}
(if you are interested in the proofs search *sr.pdf* in my Home Page, I don't transcribe here because, more than a question, this should become an article)

**My question:**

Suppose using this equation with a finite monodimensional hole:
\begin{equation*}
U(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-V_0 & \quad \textrm{if }-a<x<a\\
0 & \quad \textrm{if }|x|>a
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
In the internal region $\Psi$ is sinusoidal (with the not restrictive condition $E>-V_0$), but in the external region we get
\begin{equation*}
 \Psi'' = k^2 \Psi ;\qquad k = \frac{\sqrt{-E (E + 2 mc^2)}}{c \hbar}
\end{equation*}
If $-2mc^2 <E <0$, $k \in \mathbb{R}^+$, otherwise $k$ is purely imaginary, the wave function is sinusoidal and the normalization is impossible. Not surprising that for $E>0$ we don't have stationary states with that finite hole, but:

- what about the case $E<-2mc^2$? What does it mean?

The only reasonable interpretation I found, is that in this case the particle is totally confined into the hole. 
 - Is this wrong?

Comment: Your Klein-Gordon equation, in presence of potential is not correct, it is (($\hat E - \hat U)^2 - \hat P^2 - m^2) \psi=0$

Comment: My equation is Wachter's one with V=U-mc^2, but except this case, I really never found K-G equation written with potential, neither mine nor your. Can you say to me more about your K-G equation? What is the P? Where I can find this way of writing K-G equation?

Comment: $\hat P^i$ is the momentum operator $(-i\hbar \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}})$, and $\hat P^2 = \sum\limits_i \hat P^i \hat P^i$ is the squared norm operator, that is $ (-\hbar^2 \nabla^2)$. For the Klein-Gordon equation with potential, see for instance equations $(45), (46)$ page $7$  in this [paper](http://www.physics.ucdavis.edu/~cheng/teaching/230A-s07/rqm2_rev.pdf). In the paper, $U=e\phi$ is the electromagnetic potential energy.

Comment: I fear we're using two different formalism, and I don't know your (with 4-vector). Now I'm leaving: I'll try to reflect upon what you wrote.

Comment: If in my stationary equation you replace $U$ with $U+mc^2$, and set $c=1$, you obtain your equation. Despite two different choice in unit and in setting zero $U$, we wrote the same thing. But the choice of $U=0$ shouldn't play any role. If we add arbitrary $\xi$ to $U$ in the above finite hole, with my equation we find normalization condition $\xi - 2mc^2 <E<\xi$, while using your we find $\xi - 2mc^2 <E - mc^2<\xi$. But in your equation $E$ is the total relativistic energy so our normalization condition are the same: if the hole is sufficiently deep (and large) the confinement seems possible.

Comment: The total  energy $E$ (in my conventions) is certainly positive. So, with your conventions (I think you take $E' = E- mc^2$), you have necessarily $E' \geq  - mc ^2$

Comment: I'm confused. If your $E$ is $E_0+K+U$ and $U$ depends arbitrarily from the $U=0$ choice, why it can't be negative? Furthermore normalizability condition involve the difference between the $\xi$ energy corresponding to the external region and the total energy $E$. Why, with a sufficiently deep hole (and large enought that the ground state has sufficiently low $K$) this difference can't be greater than $mc^2$?

Comment: We can rearrange my question in this way (no matter if in our equation what we call $E$ include or not rest energy): is it true that if the hole is deeper than $$ mc^2 \left( 1 + \sqrt{ 1+\left( \frac{h}{4amc} \right)^2 } \right) $$ there is a finite number of stationary states for wich wave function is completely confined into the hole? (for example if the hole il large 2 fm and we use electron mass, the hole has to be deep al least 310.4719 MeV)

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that $\Psi$ is confined we must have $\Psi=0$ in the external region, so in the border of internal region we must have $\Psi=0$ and $\frac{d\Psi}{dx}=0$. But with our flat $U$, stationary K-G equation say that $\Psi$ is sinusoidal or exponential, so this requisites cannot be satisfied sumultaneously. Conclusion: the confinement of $\Psi$ is impossible (simply, stationary states with $E<-2mc^2$ are impossibile).